# Issue With Looping/Variables Through HTML Table Elements

Tags: html, excel, for-loop, vba

I have this project I'm working on which involves tracking the order statuses of individual shipments from a list of URLs on an Excel sheet. Currently, the code is able to loop through the URLs fine and extract information from them, but when I try to add exceptions and variables to the loop for each different URL, I get a type mismatch. Currently, there are 3 variables I need in order to extract the HTML information from the HTMLCollection/Table. What I'm trying to do here is:

- Cycle through each URL (inserts URL in IE and keeps going without opening new tabs)
- Obtain the status of the item for each URL from the HTML element
- FedEx: Delivered (td class="status")
- UPS: Delivered (id="tt_spStatus")
- USPS: Arrived at USPS Facility (class= "info-text first)

My code:

```
Sub TrackingDeliveryStatusUpdate()

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = True

Dim rngURL As Range
Dim wb1 As Workbook, ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim MyURL As String
Dim Rows As Long, links As Variant, IE As InternetExplorer, link As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim sID As String
Dim rngLinks As Range, rngLink As Range


Dim filterRange As Range
Dim copyRange As Range
'Dim doc As Object

Set wb1 = Application.Workbooks.Open("\\S51\Store51\Employee Folders\Jason\TrackingDeliveryStatus.xls")
Set ws1 = wb1.Worksheets("TrackingDeliveryStatusResults")
'Set rngURL = ws1.Range("C2:C" & lastRow)
'Arr = rngURL
Set IE = New InternetExplorer

Rows = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set rngLinks = ws1.Range("C2:C" & Rows)

'Loop through each used cell in column C on sheet URLs
'For Each rngURL In Worksheets("TrackingDeliveryStatusResults").Range("C2", Worksheets("TrackingDeliveryStatusResults").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
'Set HTMLDoc = IE.Document
With IE
    .Visible = True
    i = 2
    For Each rngLink In rngLinks
        .Navigate (rngLink)
        While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
        'If InStr(1, URL.Value, "fedex") Then sID = "status"
                Dim doc As Object
                Set doc = IE.Document
                'I know this line right below is a big mess. Not sure what to do here.
                If InStr(1, rngLink.Value2, "ups") Then
                    sID = "tt_spStatus"
        'If InStr(3, URL.Value, "usps") Then sID = "info-text first"

                    ws1.Range("D" & i).Value = doc.getElementById(sID).Items(0).Value
        'ws1.Range("D" & i).Value = .Document.body.innerText
                End If

    Next rngLink
    i = i + 1
End With


Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True



End Sub
```

I figured this would work, but apparently it doesn't with referencing URLs from an Excel spreadsheet.[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should dim `Link` and `Links` as range and change:

```
links = ws1.Range("C2:C" & Rows)
```

to:

```
Set Links = ws1.Range("C2:C" & Rows)
```

You are trying to make a Variant equal a Range which can't happen. But once you set `Links` to the range of cells, then when you're looping through each cell reference the URL with `link.Value2`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is not working is because you have several concepts mixed up in your statements. I have refactored the relevant parts of the code and made some suggestions on variable type and name changes

```
Dim rngLinks as Range, rngLink as Range

Set rng Links = ws1.Range("C2:C" & Rows)

For each rngLink in rngLinks
```

Just because here you are looping through cells in a worksheet range.

Then inside the `For each rngLink in rngLinks` statement, after the statement where the code waits for IE to load.

```
Dim doc as Object
Set doc = .document

If InStr(1, rngLink.Value2, "ups") Then 
     sID = "tt_spStatus"
     ws1.Range("D" & I).Value = doc.getElementById(sID).Items(0).Value
End If
```

You can also delete the `For Each TDelement In sID` block. It is not needed.

Comment: Should sID be dimmed/declared as IHTMLElementCollection? I might be missing something, though. I know it's my fault that the thing is still giving me a type mismatch. Not sure what I'm doing wrong on my end. T_T I've inserted the code properly and it's still giving me the error since it's before the loop.

Comment: sorry, sID should be a `String` variable, as you are passing the id/element name.

Comment: Alright, thanks. I'm now running into the error with the last line before the If statement saying that the object doesn't support this property or method (Runtime Error: 438). I'm using Office 2010 Professional, which should have this method.

Comment: what line is it exactly?

Comment: I debugged it all the way until `ws1.Range("D" & I).Value = .getElementById(sID).Items(0).Value` and that's when the error is thrown. The browser is able to get to the ups website, then the macro errors out. If it does this with one address, it's sure to apply to the rest of them as well.

Comment: Should it be "doc.getElementById..." instead of calling it directly on the IE object?

Comment: @Tak - as barrow commented, it should be `doc.getElementById...` I was mixing up the `With block`. I have edited my code. Please try again.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I made the small change, and it's still throwing the error. Am I putting the If statement in the right place? I've updated the code for reference.

Comment: @Tak in `getElementById("sID")` the `sID` should not be in quotes. so just `getElementById(sID)`

Comment: @tak - if you keep editing the code in your original question, it will become impossible for others to track the original problem and the answer.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I've tried both ways, and the closest I could get for anything to run is if I changed `ws1.Range("D" & i).Value = doc.getElementByID(sID).Items(0).Value` to `ws1.("D" & i).Value = doc.getElementByID("tt_spStatus")` T_T and even then the loop stopped after it went through the UPS website, and nothing showed up to the right of the UPS address column.

Comment: if you do a debug on the line `doc.getElementByID("tt_spStatus")` or `doc.getElementByID("tt_spStatus").Value` or `doc.getElementByID("tt_spStatus").Items(0).Value` what do you get?

Comment: For the debug on the line `doc.getElementByID("tt_spStatus")` I get a "javascript:void(0)" on the second row in column D, and nothing else.
For the debug on the other two, the same Error 438 comes up.